# Are WhatsApp voice calls recorded on your device?

Tags: ios, whatsapp.app

I know voice calling on WhatsApp is logged but is it stored on the device in a way you can re listen to the conversation?  I looked in the WhatsApp folders and everything is there from voice notes, photos, videos, etc. and there is nothing there for voice calling.

Are WhatsApp calls recorded and stored on the device or is it just a log where you can see you made a call?

Comment: only whatsapp can answer that, but i don't think they would save the calls just the logs.

Answer (score 1):

The audio of the calls is not recorded and is not available in the app container.

Comment: are they recorded on server?

Comment: @Stepan Definitely not in a user-accessible form

Comment: NSA has its users probably.